# Magento EE 2.1.5 Deactivate Campaign manually

Tags: magento2.1.5, schedule, staging

I need to deactivate a campaign manually from database in Magento EE 2.1.5 . I searched a lot, but I did  not found any way to do that.

What are the tables which store the campaign's data? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is that :

- searched for product by SKU in catalog_product_entity table. (Found
  multiple rows).
- Copy row_id from catalog_product_entity and search for it in
  catalog_product_entity_datetime
- Update the dates in catalog_product_entity_datetime table.